# How can the satellite photos of Bucha show dead bodies weeks ago? Wouldn't the bodies decompose?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, propaganda

(Not sure if this should be on the biology SE; also not sure what to tag this with so feel free to edit)

There are [several](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/04/world/europe/bucha-ukraine-bodies.html) [sources](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/apr/05/satellite-images-of-corpses-in-bucha-prove-russian-claims-wrong) claiming that bodies can be seen in Bucha before the Russian retreat, and therefore they cannot be Ukrainian propaganda.

A quick Google search indicates that [human bodies decay visibly within 3-5 days](https://www.aftermath.com/content/human-decomposition/):

> 24-72 hours after death — the internal organs decompose.
>
> 3-5 days after death — the body starts to bloat and blood-containing foam leaks from the mouth and nose.
>
> 8-10 days after death — the body turns from green to red as the blood decomposes and the organs in the abdomen accumulate gas.

Given this, how is it possible that the bodies were visible two weeks before the Russian withdrawal? If they have been there for two weeks, how is it that the bodies haven't visibly decomposed?

A first guess is that the temperatures in Bucha are low enough that the bodies are preserved, but another Google search indicates that the temperatures are [between 2C to 13C](https://meteotrend.com/temperature/de/bucha/), which doesn't seem cold enough to preserve the bodies.

Comment: "which doesn't seem cold enough to preserve the bodies" your linked source says "It's a natural process ***that varies*** *based on ph and oxygen level, the cause of death, weather, **temperature and even the moisture level.***" and perhaps *The U.S. Sun* is not the right source to fact-base the premise of your question. I think Biology SE (as you mention) or better yet Skeptics SE would be a good place, but I don't think there are political aspects to the temperature dependent rate of whole human body decomposition.

Comment: I think that this is currently off topic as-asked, and may be closed as such. I think it's an excellent Skeptics SE question, but there are no political aspects to the rate at which human body decomposition and visibility of the *winter clothing they are wearing* from satellites in orbit, so no political answers can be forthcoming. If you want to ask here, you have to fact-base your premise, and neither "doesn't seem cold enough" nor "*A priori* it seems probable to me..." are sufficient to do that.

Comment: I’m sorry, but the decomposition of bodies is not on-topic for this site. One option would be to ask how the Ukrainian government has responded to such claims.

Comment: The satellite images aren't high-resolution enough that you'd be able to *see* the decomposition. I've seen some of them and the people in the streets just look like indistinct black blobs.

Comment: @F1 the satellite images are 2 weeks old. If there is decomposition, it would be in the photos being taken today, not in the satellite images.

Comment: @Giter Most of the images I've seen (just Google for "Bucha massacre") have had bodies that look pretty not-decomposed. Still, I am not an expert on what decomposing bodies should look like. If you know then it's an answer, although the question is closed.

Comment: The picture of the infamous 4-5 naked female bodies, tossed during their retreat from a Russian column and trying to set it on fire, does *indeed* show reddish bodies.  And it maybe a good example of what's that looks like.  You listed 3 stages in the question.  But it is the 4th stage(described on the same site you cited) when the actual decomposition takes place.  Also the temperatures at night are about 15 degrees colder.  So it often drops below 32F.  Because bodies have lots of fluids, even when the temperature rises during the day, it takes hours for bodies to reach ambient temperature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**They would *start to* decompose. They would not become skeletons instantly.**

In an average year, in [March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyiv#Climate) the area around Kyiv will have temperatures above freezing. But the *average* daily temperature is lower than that of the non-freezer compartment of a refrigerator.

Some of the victims have been matched to satellite pictures from early in the war. Others are more recent.

Even so, reporters talk about [bodies left to rot](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/04/05/europe/bucha-ukraine-russian-occupation-reality-intl-cmd/index.html).

---

I agree with the comments that this would be a good fit for Sceptics SE, but communication about this is a highly political process right now ...